# Create a table with oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I get this error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, but I cannot see what the problem is.

Creates the package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "TOOL_PKG" IS 
   PROCEDURE CREATE_ZTEMP_CLAIMS_TABLES;
END TOOL_PKG;
/
```

Create a procedure for the package. I get the error trying to run the procedure.

What I want to do is create a new table with an existing table. I need it dynamic because I'll be adding a lot more tables to the list.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CUBS_OWNER."TOOL_PKG" IS 
PROCEDURE CREATE_NEW_TABLE IS

        type array_t is table of varchar2(50) index by pls_integer;
        my_table_t array_t;
        elem varchar2(50);
        c int;
    BEGIN
        my_table_t (1) := 'MY_TABLE';

        elem := my_table_t.first;
        while elem is not null loop
            select count(*) into c from user_tables where table_name = upper('ZTEST_'||my_table_t(elem));
            if c=0 then
                 Begin
                    execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE upper(NEWX_'||my_table_t(elem)||') AS SELECT * FROM upper('||my_table_t(elem)||') where rownum=0';
                    COMMIT;
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ZTEST_'||my_table_t(elem)||' created.');
                 EXCEPTION
                 WHEN OTHERS
                    THEN
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                        'tool_pkg.create_new_table...failed creating table '
                        || CHR (10)
                        || SQLERRM);
                 END;
            end if;
            elem := my_table_t.next(elem);
        end loop;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
               'tool_pkg.create_new_table...failed creating table  '
            || CHR (10)
            || SQLERRM);
   END;

END tool_pkg;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure the methods upper were outside the quotes.

Instead of this

```
execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE upper(NEWX_'||my_table_t(elem)||') AS SELECT * FROM upper('||my_table_t(elem)||') where rownum=0';
```

It had to be in this form

```
execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE '||upper('NEWX_'||my_table_t(elem))||' AS SELECT * FROM '||upper(my_table_t(elem))||' where rownum=0';
```